# Hide developer tool for non-administrator

Tags: odoo

I want to hide the *Open Developer Tools* button for non-administrators.

[image]

When I search the solution on the internet, I find the module to hide that button, but I have to pay about $50. Is there a solution to achieve those things without having to pay?

I have already deactivated developer mode. But the weird thing is, the *Open Developer Tools* button is hidden for admin, but is shown for non-admin.

[image]

Comment: There is no really big harm for non admin accounts using that tool, because normal users only see a limited set of features under that menu. But i can understand, if someone don't want to show it to normal users at all.

Comment: Yes, but I want to hide that button because it looks ugly for a regular employee.

Comment: Can you just deactivate the developer mode in the setting?

Comment: Yes, I already did. But it still appears on non-admin.

Comment: Maybe you deactivated the developer mode in the admin user and not the non-admin users. Double check this.

Comment: IIRC you can't deactivate it, because every user can activate it by manipulating the URL.

Comment: Then maybe you need to override the CSS of li.o_debug_manager to add {display: none !important;}. That may do the trick. Not tested though.

Comment: @NMNaufaldo Did you succeed to hide the debug button from regular users?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the `WebClient.DebugManager` template to add a condition on the menu item.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="WebClient.DebugManager">
        <t t-jquery="li" t-operation="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-if">widget.is_admin</attribute>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Then extend the `web.DebugManager` widget to set the value of `is_admin`:

```js
odoo.define('MODULE_NAME.DebugManager', function(require) {
    'use strict';
    var DebugManager = require('web.DebugManager');
    var session = require('web.session');
    DebugManager.include({
        init: function () {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.is_admin = session.is_system;
        },
    });
});
```

You can check  [how to add a file in an asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) and [how to extend templates](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/qweb.html#template-inheritance) in Odoo documentation.

***For Odoo 16***
Override the `web.DebugMenu` template. `isAdmin` value is available through `env.services.user.isAdmin`

***Example:***

```xml
<t t-inherit="web.DebugMenu" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//Dropdown" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="t-if">env.services.user.isAdmin</attribute>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this! can you update it for the usage in Odoo 16?

Comment: Of course, I will adapt it to the framework changes.

Comment: I added a working example for Odoo 16